# For each $a \in U$ we have $Df(a):\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a linear isomorphism

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

An invertible function $f: U \subseteq \mathbb R^n \to V \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is given and we know that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ both are differentiable.

Prove that for each $a \in U$ we have $Df(a):\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a linear isomorphism. Then for $b \in V$, find $Df^{-1}(b)$.

I can't even understand how this is possible! For example, How can derivatives of $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ itself?

Comment: For your last case, note this. Let $$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$ given by $$f(x)=x^3.$$

Then $$f'(x)=3x^2.$$

Note that for each $x$ the derivative gives a linear mapping on $\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$T_x(t)=f'(x)\cdot t.$$

So for example, when $x=1$, the linear mapping becomes

$$T_1(t)=3t$$ 
which is clearly an isomorphism.

Note also that since the inverse of $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, the linear mapping

$$T_0(t)=0t=0$$

is not an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to V \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is said to be differentiable if there exists a linear map $\lambda$ such that,

$$ \lim_{x \to p} \frac{\|f(x) - f(p) - \lambda(x-p)\|}{\|x-p\|} = 0 \ \ \ \ \textbf{or} \ \ \ \ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|f(p+h) - f(p) -\lambda(h) \|}{\|h\|} = 0$$

for all $p \in U$. What this means is that $\lambda$ is a linear map which approximates the change in $f$ for points $x$ sufficiently close to $p$. By the above definition, $\lambda$ is also unique. One can show that,

$$\tilde{\lambda}(\textbf{h}) =  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x^1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x^n} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial f^m}{\partial x^1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f^m}{\partial x^n} \end{pmatrix} \cdot \textbf{h}, \ \ \ \textrm{where} \ \ \ \ f = \begin{pmatrix} f^1 \\ f^2 \\ \vdots \\ f^m \end{pmatrix}$$

is a map which satisfies the above defintion and so $\tilde{\lambda} = \lambda$. From the definition above it is clear that $\lambda$ is linear. Instead of using $\lambda$ we adopt a different notation $D_pf$ or $Df(p)$. Typically one makes no distinction between a linear map (on a f.d.v.s) but since this may be your first time seeing this, one can define the matrix above as the Jacobian $\textbf{J}(Df(p))$ and let $Df(p)$ be the corresponding linear operator.

\begin{align*} Df(p): &\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m \\& v \mapsto \textbf{J}_p(v) \end{align*}

By the chain rule, given $\gamma: (- \epsilon, \epsilon) \to U$ is a smooth curve with $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$ we have a relation,

\begin{align*} \frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t = 0} (f \circ \gamma)(t) &= Df(\gamma(0)) \cdot \gamma'(0) \\ & = Df(p) \cdot v \\ & = \textbf{J}_p(v) \end{align*}

Comment: You said "invertible" but wrote the definition of "diferentiable".

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: That was clearly a mistake. I've made an edit.

Comment: On the other hand, everything you have written is fine, but nowhere I see where you address the questions in the post.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: The OP questioned how could the derivative be a linear map. This is what I've explained. The other user shows how one can use the chain rule to get $Df^{-1}$. So yes, I refrained from giving a direct answer since I believe this insight about the derivative as a linear map will allow the OP to answer his/her own question.

Answer (score 0):

You have $f \circ f^{-1} = I$ and $f^{-1}\circ f = I$. Take the derivative of both sides in each equation and apply the chain rule. Conclude.

Comment: I think his problem is not in applicating theorems, but in seeing how the derivative $D_a f$ can be seen as a linear mapping, starting from the $n=1$ case.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?u just wrote some trivial statements... How are these used to prove that $Df(a)$ is a linear isomorphism?

Comment: @PaoloMolina: These are not just trivial statements. This user actually did answer your questions. He/she is showing you that if you apply chain rule to the above statements you will see that $Df^{-1} = (Df)^{-1}$.